# How do I install subtree that ships with official Git install?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I downloaded and installed the latest Git version 1.8.4.2 from http://git-scm.com. I expected various third party Git modules such as Subtree to be available in `/usr/local/git/contrib` for installation. However, the `contrib` folder only contains a single folder (`completion`) inside of it and no other files or folders.

So I have two questions:

Why are modules missing from the `contrib` folder?

How do I install `Subtree` in absence of the same from the `contrib` folder? (I would prefer installing Subtree from official Git source rather than from https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree which is now an obsolete repo)

BTW, I'm running OS X Mavericks

Comment: Git subtree is part of standard git installation - what does `git subtree` say?

Comment: It says `Subtree` is not a git command. Though subtree is part of standard git installation, by default it is not installed and is available inside of the contrib folder for installation. That's from where I have installed it in the past. Though this time around I'm missing subtree and other modules from the contrib folder.

Comment: Perhaps `subtree` instead of `Subtree`?

Comment: @twalberg Well, as I mentioned there is no other folder in `contrib` other than the `completion` folder. And this is a mystery to me. I just re-installed git from the installer and same thing again. Did they remove the modules from the latest installer?

Comment: As @user1615903 mentions, `subtree` is no longer in the `contrib` section - it's included in the main distribution now. My point was that it's all lower-case, but you've mentioned the capitalized `Subtree` twice now, which is incorrect, so checking that you're using the right spelling (`git subtree`) was a good idea...

Comment: @twalberg Yes, I just cross checked and can confirm that I'm typing it in lowercase in terminal. While googling for answer to this issue, almost all blog I came across mention installing `subtree` from the `contrib` folder, that has been there from git 1.7.11. For example in this article here http://engineeredweb.com/blog/how-to-install-git-subtree/. Under the section Mac OS X 10.8 > Git From Installer

Comment: @twalberg The same article mentions installing subtree from the git source. I'm trying the same out. Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple ways to install git subtree on mac depending on how you installed git on your system.

### With Homebrew

If you used [**homebrew**](http://brew.sh/) to install git then subtree, along with the rest of the git contrib items, was already placed on your system and can be installed. To install subtree:

1. Fire up a terminal and go to **`/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/subtree`**.
2. Run `make` which will prepare subtree.
3. Run `make prefix=/usr/local/opt/git/ install`. The prefix is important because the default location the makefile knows about is not where it needs to be installed with homebrew.

### Git From Installer

If you downloaded and installed git using the installer from the [**git website**](http://www.git-scm.com/) there is a different method to installing git-subtree:

1. Since git contrib was not put on your system you'll need to checkout the [**git source**](https://github.com/git/git). Don't worry about compiling or installing git. You just need access to the contrib director to install subtree (which is mostly shell scripts).
2. In a terminal go into the **`git/contrib/subtree`** directory.
3. Run **`make`** to prepare subtree.
4. Run **`sudo make prefix=/usr install`**. The prefix is important for it to be installed in the right location. *Note, you need to use sudo to install this because of it's location on the system.*
5. Remove the git source (unless you want to keep it around for another reason).

reference: [**how-to-install-git-subtree**](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/how-to-install-git-subtree/)

Comment: Just to say, the installer (OSX) put git in `/usr/local/git`, so I had to used `sudo make prefix=/usr/local/git/ install`

Comment: The "Git from Installer" method took some adjusting on my slightly older Debian 7 server. I successfully got the "git subtree" command to work, but had some compatibility issues. The first error: "shift: can't shift that many". I fixed it by doing some googling and fixing the incompatibility with my bash version, I think? (4.2.37). Next error: fatal: unrecognized argument: --no-show-signature. Fixed that too by removing all uses of the "--no-show-signature flag"... Not sure what a more robust solution would be right now.

Answer (score 1):

The current Homebrew-installed git (v2.4.1) does seem to come with git-subtree out of box. Just doing `brew install git` or `brew update && brew upgrade git` might do the trick.

Comment: Just small tip to override system link on Mac (after Xcode or self installation) `brew link --overwrite git`.

Answer (score 0):

git subtree install appears to be broken in the latest **git version 2.27.0**

```
https://github.com/git/git
```

I built and installed from top level no problem: `make; make install`.

```
git: 'subtree' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Switched to `contrib/subtree`, `make; make install`. Still no ***subtree*** command. Tried `make prefix=~/; make prefix=~/ install`. Still no ***subtree*** command.

Turns out `git-subtree` was infact siting there in `contrib/subtree`. So I copied it to `~/bin` and now it works (smoke coming out of head...).